# Discovering Bluetooth devices quickly

Tags: bluetooth

What I want to do is this:
I have a database with certain Bluetooth devices (BD_ADDR). I want to discover if any of the devices is within range and if so, tell it to do something.
One way is to run discovery all the time, create a list of the devices discovered and compare it against the database. If a device present in the database is found, I open connection with it and tell it to do something.
The problem is that this process is slow and to reliably find all the devices, the inquiry length must be big and the process must be repeated all the time.

My idea is to discover my Bluetooth once only, pair it with my device, and from then on whenever the device comes in range, to make a connection with it not by going through lengthy discovery but somehow using the information I already have for this device.

In other words, is it possible to use the information I already know about a device (having paired with it before or just having had a connection with it) to start communicating with it without having to discover it first?

Thank you,
donescamilloATgmail.com

Answer (score 0):

What library are you using for bluetooth and what kind of socket do you plan to communicate with? In most cases, you should be able to just create a socket connection to the device if you know its BD_ADDR. For instance, in BlueZ, you only need to write the following to create an RFCOMM connection to a known server on channel 1:

```
struct sockaddr_rc addr = { 0 };
int s, status;

// destination address
char dest[18] = "00:17:EC:35:96:FF";

// allocate a socket
s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

// set the connection parameters (who to connect to)
addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
addr.rc_channel = 1;
str2ba( dest, &addr.rc_bdaddr );

// connect to server
status = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using BTstack on Windows. 
Not sure if it implements socket communication.
Just to confirm-if I have a BD_ADDRESS of a device, I do not need any other information (like clockOffset etc.) in order to connect to it (one way or another, I will find out how exactly). 
Is that the case?

Thanks,
donescamilloATgmail.com

Comment: Yup that's right. You don't really need to know anything other than the BD_ADDR to connect to a device. You will need to make sure however that the device supports the socket communication you're attempting to use. RFCOMM is arguably the most common socket used, so I'd be surprised if BTStack doesn't implement it.